# JSON to INSERT SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I've been looking everywhere, can't seem to find a solution. I have a very long string in a textfile. It's already in a Json format i.e.

`[{"column":"data", "anothercolumn":"data"}, {"column":"data", "anothercolumn": "data"}]`

I want to convert this to an INSERT MS SQL statement using C#. Is there any way to do this? I can't figure it out myself using DeserializeObject or DataSets and DataTables. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the following [Json to C# Class Converter](http://json2csharp.com/) from there you could get the data into a Class and from there into DataTables etc.. or[ convert the json to CSV](http://konklone.io/json/)

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If you have a known database structure, then deserializing the JSON string using a POCO object created by (for example) EF will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Deserialize the JSON string into an array of dictionaries.
2. Loop through the array.
3. Using the dictionary keys, create an SQL statement of the form: `INSERT INTO myTable (key1, key2, ...) VALUES (@key1, @key2, ...)`.
4. Looping through the dictionary's key-value-pairs, add the values as parameters: `AddWithValue("@" + key, value)`.
5. Execute the SQL statement.
6. Profit.

The implementation is left as an exercise.